# using Generics in GWT JsInterop: Uncaught java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: javascript, java, gwt

I have an interface annotated with @JsFunction that I use as a callback for events. As there are different types of events, I have added a type parameter:

```
@JsFunction
public interface Function<T extends Event>{

  public JavaScriptObject call(T event);

}
```

From the entry point I do something like :

```
//...

map.on("click", new Function<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public JavaScriptObject call(MouseEvent event) {

    });
```

When I run the project, everything compiles and run fine. But when the code above is executed, I get the following exception in the console:

Uncaught java.lang.ClassCastException              InternalPreconditions.java:45

This seems like a GWT internal error. Is this a known bug in GWT 2.8 ? Are generics not allowed with JsInterop types?

Comment: Are you using the nightly? Closer to rc1?

Comment: No using beta1. I tried using the nightly build, but it does not really solve this issue.

Comment: I ended up using JSNI and the cast() method of the JavaScriptObject class: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-web-toolkit/B668g4J4tkw